# nginx + uwsgi + Django does not use environment variables set in venv activate script

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi, python-venv

Tldr; Environment variables set in my venv's activate script are not being utilized by Django when accessing the application through the production web server.

Stack: nginx -> uwsgi -> django + venv

Like many other folks, I am trying to move my sensitive key information out of my settings.py file. To do this, I have added multiple export statements to the end of the activate script for my local venv environment.

settings.py

```
SECRET_KEY =  os.environ.get('DJANGO_PROJECT_KEY', '********************')
DEBUG = os.environ.get('DJANGO_PROJECT_DEBUG', '') != 'False'
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ.get('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID', '')
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ.get('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY', '')
```

env/bin/activate

```
export SECRET_KEY = '*********************'
export DEBUG="True"
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="********************"
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="**************************"
```

From there, I can reload the environment and confirm that they key value pairs are available by running

```
python manage.py shell
>> import os
>> os.environ
```

Which shows the correct values for the keys. Additionally, I can launch the development server with

```
python manage runserver 0:8080
```

And am able to post files to the AWS S3 bucket as desired. However, once I reboot the server to restart the uWSGI process and access the site from its domain through nginx, I am unable to post files to S3. Instead I get a NoCredentials error, despite the fact that I can see the relevant AWS key information in the settings information available when the debug setting is set to TRUE.

project.ini

```
# initialize the uwsgi instance to connect nginx to django
[uwsgi]

# base directory of project
chdir       = /home/ubuntu/project/project

# django wsgi file in python module syntax
module      = project.wsgi

# path to the virtual environment
home        = /home/ubuntu/project/env
...
# clear the environemtn on exit
vacuum      = true
```

etc/nginx/sites-enabled/project.conf

```
upstream django {
    server unix:///tmp/project/uwsgi.sock;
}

server {
    listen      80;
    server_name mydomain.in;
    charset     utf-8;
    client_max_body_size 250M;

    location /media  {
        alias /home/ubuntu/project/media;
    }

    location /static {
        alias /home/ubuntu/project/project/static;
    }

    location / {
        uwsgi_pass  django;
        include     /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;
    }
}
```

I am able to upload files when using uwsgi by itself to access the Django project.

```
uwsgi --http 0:8080 --wsgi-file project/wsgi.py
```

Why are the variables exported in the activate script available when launching the development server but not when accessing the project through nginx / uWSGI?

Answer (score 1):

A simple fix for the credentials stuff I did is below:

```
with open('credentials.txt', 'r') as credentials:
    for lines in credentials.read().split('\n'):
        dbcreden.append(lines.strip())
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': dbcreden[0],
    'USER':dbcreden[1],
    'PASS':dbcreden[2],
    'HOST':'localhost',
    'PORT': '3306'
    }
}
```

And for the secret key something similar:

```
with open('secretkey.txt') as f:
    SECRET_KEY = f.read().strip()
```

This is also advised in the official django docs, so it should be secure.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

Comment: Yes, this is more or less the solution that I opted for, but I used the django-environ package to provide a ready to go solution for reading .env files. I personally prefer keeping the string manipulation outside of my settings file for readability.